# Peaks, Valleys, and Slopes

Tags: riddle, rhyme, limerick

> I have peaks and valleys and slopes
>   Whose mountains and beats are such tropes,
>     And the prime, you will find,
>     Is a step back in time;
>   The end, you will find, is a hoax.

What am I?

Hints:

> It's not "music."
>  It's not "rhymes" or anything to do with poetry.
>  It's not "waves," but is the closest guess so far (a square is a rectangle).
>  It's not a "desert," especially since the mountains and beats portion of the limerick isn't fully satisfied.
>  It's not "the ocean," and is, in fact, the wrong direction to take the "waves" hint.
>  Some words are more literal than they first appear.
>  "Tropes" has a double meaning here.

Comment: The first two lines sound like music, but not sure how this fits the rest.

Comment: Waves?.........

Comment: Is the space in line 3 and 4 supposed to be there?

Comment: @Wouter Yes, the space is supposed to be there since it's a limerick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it a:

> Sinusoidal wave? -updated thanks to **ace**

I have peaks and valleys and slopes

> These waves have all of these things - peaks/troughs.

Whose mountains and beats are such tropes,

> Constructive / destructive interference of two longitudinal sound waves causes the phenomena known as beats.

And the prime, you will find,
  Is a step back in time;

> The derivation of the wave is the same wave phase-shifted (or, how it would have appeared at a certain time beforehand)

The end, you will find, is a hoax.

> Because there is no finite end to a longitudinal wave - thanks @Mark N

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of Sine wave, but wasn't sure since he mentions It's not "waves,"

Comment: Yeah, that threw me too.

Comment: There is no finite end to a Longitudinal wave, it is a 'hoax'

Comment: You are correct! The key here was the two prime lines. The derivative (the prime) of a longitudinal wave function is the same wave moments earlier. sin(x)` = cos(x).

Comment: @MarkN My hint with the "waves" was that a square is a rectangle. The prime lines are the part that "differentiated" it from other types of waves.

Comment: @alexmc The word "tropes" here has a double meaning. The first meaning is that mountains and beats are figurative language for how a wave behaves (which you already mentioned), and the second meaning is that they are recurring.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson How does transverse wave not fit the riddle?

Comment: @ace I just did my research, and you're right. Both transverse and longitudinal waves can be broken down into sine wave functions, so technically, you were the first person to answer the riddle correctly. Sorry for that. When I designed my riddle, it was with sinusoidal waves in mind.

Comment: @alexmc So, technically, thanks to ace, the real answer should be "Sinusoidal Wave."

Answer (score 5):

I think it might be

> a RHYME.

*I have peaks and valleys and slopes

 Whose mountains and beats are such tropes,*

> These two lines rhyme; the first is a reference to the rhythm of a poem or verse, and the second could be the same.

*And the prime, you will find,

   Is a step back in time;*

> "Prime" with the first letter removed (a step back?) is "rime", a homophone of "rhyme".

*The end, you will find, is a hoax.*

> The last line of the limerick doesn't actually rhyme with the first two - it's a hoax limerick!

Comment: It's a partial rhyme.

Comment: Valley and slopes sounds like scansion notation, though I don't know about peaks.

Comment: +1 This is quite a creative answer! However, it's not the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> The desert

I have peaks and valleys and slopes

> A desert have peaks, valleys and slopes (dunes)

Whose mountains and beats are such tropes,

> I don't understand this sentence but i guess mountain could refer to dune again

And the prime, you will find,
  Is a step back in time;

> When you desert, it's a step back from your first decision

The end, you will find, is a hoax.

> Maybe the fact that you can see oasis if you walk too long in the desert

Comment: +1 Creative! I added some more hints if you care to look.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> The Ocean?

I have peaks and valleys and slopes
Whose mountains and beats are such tropes

> It has "mountains and valleys" in the form of waves - but they aren't real mountains (tropes).

And the prime, you will find,
Is a step back in time;

> The first wave happened a looooong time ago.

The end, you will find, is a hoax.

> At the "end" of the ocean appears the horizon, which is a hoax in that it's not a real thing and will continue to move further away from you.

Comment: +1 This is quite close, actually, so I added some more hints.